# Laravel factory is creating PK column with the name Id instead of the given one

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, factory

I've got the following factory:

```
$factory->define(App\Product::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'product_name' => $faker->sentence($nbWords = 4, $variableNbWords = true),
        'product_description' => $faker->paragraph($nbSentences = 6, $variableNbSentences = true),
        'product_price' => $faker->numberBetween($min=500, $max=2000),
    ];
});
```

and the following migration:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('product_id');
            $table->string('product_name', 356)->nullable(false);
            $table->longText('product_description')->nullable();
            $table->integer('product_price')->nullable(false);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

After running the factory and printing out a newly created product, it says that the PK is 'id' instead of 'product_id'. When trying to access $product->product_id is returning null because obviously that doesn't exists according to the factory.

While inspecting the DB table I can confirm that the column is named product_id and not 'id'.

I already ran:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

and then ran the migration again but still getting the wrong data back.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, you should override the default by setting this in your model.

```
protected $primaryKey = 'product_id';
```

Don't forget to make the necessary changes in your table relationships (hasManys, belongTos etc...)

Answer (score 0):

You can change to:

```
$table->integer('product_id')->primary();
```

Comment: I tried that but when running the migration I'm getting the following error:

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1068 Multiple primary key defined (SQL: alter table `products` add primary key `products_product_id_primary`(`product_id`))

Comment: You must run php artisan migrate:refresh  to Reset and re-run all migrations

Comment: That's exactly what I ran

Comment: You can try $table->integer('product_id', true);